# how to call 'hide and show' jQuery code when I use jQuery validate plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have used jquery validate plugin to validate the password field, but I want to run hide and show password jquery code when click on button inside password field.

```
document.getElementById("toggle-password").classList.remove("d-none");
const passwordInput = document.querySelector("[type='password']");
const togglePasswordButton = document.getElementById("toggle-password");
togglePasswordButton.addEventListener("click", togglePassword);
function togglePassword() {
  if (passwordInput.type === "password") {
    passwordInput.type = "text";
    togglePasswordButton.setAttribute("aria-label", "Hide password.");
  } else {
    passwordInput.type = "password";
    togglePasswordButton.setAttribute(
      "aria-label",
      "Show password as plain text. " +
        "Warning: this will display your password on the screen."
    );
  }
}
```

above code I have used for hide and show password.

```
  $('form#business_register_form').validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else if (element.hasClass('input-icheck') && element.parent().hasClass('icheckbox_square-blue')) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent().parent().parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        rules: {
            name: 'required',
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
            },
    });
```

Html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="password">Password:*</label>
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
</span>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" name="password" type="password" value="" id="password" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
<button id="toggle-password" type="button" class="" aria-label="Show password as plain text. Warning: this will display your password on the screen.">
</button>
</div><label id="password-error" class="error" for="password" style="display: none;"></label>
</div>
```

but only jquery validation is working but not hide and show password is not working. please help me to fix it.

Comment: add your all code here like HTML, CSS

Comment: added @LaljiTadhani

Comment: why any event is not triggering inside form if used jquery validate plugin to validate the same form?

Comment: how to call another function on checkbox checked in jquery validation plugin